# What is the meaning of "site"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology

Reading questions, I have come across a recurring notion of "*site*". Whilst I am able to understand the questions I am unsure as to what a "site" actually is and to what it corresponds physically.

I have found sentences like:

"*Assume that the creation and annihilation operators are for states fixed at discrete sites with positions*..." or:

"This form arises from discretising kinetic energy in the cases of sites with distances 1/K".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A site is just a place or location with given coordinates e.g. $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$